# PIL TypeError: text() has multiple values for argument 'font'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have the function:

```
imagewidth = 250 
y_positions = [65.0, 85.0, 105.0, 125.0, 145.0, 165.0] 
numbers_to_show = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]

def draw_numbers(imagewidth, y_positions, numbers_to_show):
    counter = 0
    while counter < len(y_positions):
        numbers_to_show = str(numbers_to_show[counter])
        font = ImageFont.truetype("impact.ttf",20)
        img = Image.open("agepyramid.bmp")
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        draw.text(20 , y_positions[counter],numbers_to_show,(0,0,0),font=font)
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        img.save("agepyramid.bmp")
        counter = counter + 1
```

I think this function should give me a picture with the "numbers_to_show" at the "y_position" of the image, but it gives me this error:

```
draw.text(20 , y_positions[counter],numbers_to_show,(0,0,0),font=font)
TypeError: text() got multiple values for argument 'font'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 4th argument of [`Draw.text`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.text) is `font`. You provide 2 values for `font` argument - `(0, 0, 0)` (by position) and `font` (by name), and this confuses the interpreter.

I guess you want

```
draw.text((20 , y_positions[counter]), numbers_to_show, (0, 0, 0), font=font)
```

where `(0, 0, 0)` is the value for `fill` argument.

Comment: It took me several re-reads to catch what had changed. It is `draw.text( (x, y), text, color, font)` not `draw.text( x, y, text, color, font)`!!